# Did Microsoft discontinue Frontpage or replace it?

Tags: frontpage

In the past, Frontpage was Microsoft’s web-development software, but it has not been included in Microsoft Office for several versions now. I have been told that Microsoft replaced it with SharePoint, but that is a completely different software with a completely different use.

So what is the replacement for Frontpage or does Microsoft no longer have a web-development program at all?

Comment: The Wikipedia page for [Microsoft FrontPage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage) indicates that it has been discontinued after Office 2003 and replaced with [Microsoft Expression Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Web) starting with Office 2007.

Comment: Front page is the easiest to use for small website. Quite often if I use CMS like wordpress, if I want to edit stuff, I'll edit it front page. If I want to see why certain character that look the same are actually different characters, I paste that to frontpage and see the source code. Any other software that do the same?

Comment: well now you are *starting* to get into software-rec (though it could always just be phrased as *are there any programs that can do this and that* to) `;-)` Unfortunately, I cannot help you with that because I am myself trying to figure out how people make websites these days. I have no site because making modern sites is too much work to do manually by hand (the way I occasionally create a single page here or there), and I do not know of a simple program that can make modern web-development easy while keeping control over the content (Frontpage is notorious for all the junk it puts in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm voting to close this question as off topic because this is a product recommendation question.  I don't normally answer questions that should be closed, but this is a fairly simple case, so I'll go ahead and answer it.  See the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#dontask) to more information.*

You can look at [Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx).

Comment: It's no longer part of office right?

Comment: No. This is part of the [Microsoft Expression Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/).

Comment: How is this a software recommendation? The question is pretty clear: *If Microsoft discontinued Frontpage, did they replace it with something else or is there no longer a Microsoft product for making web pages?* Besides, what’s wrong with software recommendations? That’s what the *[tag:software-rec]* tag is for.

Comment: @Synetech: See http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3587/update-the-faq-to-disallow-any-product-recommendation-questions

Comment: Like I said, it’s not a software recommendation request. They are asking if Microsoft made any newer versions of Frontpage, replaced it with another software, or abandoned the web-development software field altogether. That has a definitive answer.

Comment: Front page is the easiest to use for small website. Quite often if I use CMS like wordpress, if I want to edit stuff, I'll edit it front page. If I want to see why certain character that look the same are actually different characters, I paste that to frontpage and see the source code. Any other software that do the same?